# AngularJs DOM element inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have my ng-repeat in div tag:

```
    <div ng-repeat="x in names">                                        
    <h1>{{x.product}}</h1>  
    <h2>{{x.brand}}</h2>    
    <h3>{{x.description}}</h3>  
    <h4>{{x.sum}}</h4>      
    <h5>{{x.productid}}</h5>        
    </div>
    <button ng-click="addToCart()">Add To Cart</button>
```

And my AngularJS script:

```
$scope.addToCart = function () {        

        $scope.productId = $scope.x.productid;

        $http.post("api/shoppingCart/" + $scope.productId);
    }
```

My problem is what I can't access/get {{x.productid}} value for my $scope.productid.

Comment: x is defined in another scope than your `addToCart-function` due to ngRepeat. You will have to pass the item inside the function as a variable to be able to access the data of the item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the item reference(`x`) - or the production id `x.productid` to the `addToCart` method

```js
var app = angular.module('my-app', [], function() {})

app.controller('AppController', function($scope) {

  $scope.names = [{
    product: 'a',
    productid: 1
  }, {
    product: 'b',
    productid: 2
  }, {
    product: 'c',
    productid: 3
  }, {
    product: 'd',
    productid: 4
  }];

  $scope.addToCart = function(x) {
    $scope.productId = x.productid;

    $http.post("api/shoppingCart/" + $scope.productId);
  }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="my-app" ng-controller="AppController">
  <div ng-repeat="x in names">
    <h1>{{x.product}}</h1> 
    <h2>{{x.brand}}</h2> 
    <h3>{{x.description}}</h3> 
    <h4>{{x.sum}}</h4> 
    <h5>{{x.productid}}</h5> 
    <button ng-click="addToCart(x)">Add To Cart</button>
  </div>

  <p>productId: {{productId}}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

change button like this `<button ng-click="addToCart(x.productid)">Add To Cart</button>` and your function is like

```
`$scope.addToCart = function (productid) {        



    $http.post("api/shoppingCart/" + productid);
}`
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the best possibility for you to make it work is to add the button in the `ng-repeat`:

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="x in names">                                        
    <h1>{{x.product}}</h1>  
    <h2>{{x.brand}}</h2>    
    <h3>{{x.description}}</h3>  
    <h4>{{x.sum}}</h4>      
    <h5>{{x.productid}}</h5>     
    <button ng-click="addToCart(x.productid)">Add To Cart</button>    
</div>
```

JS:

```
$scope.addToCart = function(id) {        
    $scope.productId = id;
    $http.post("api/shoppingCart/" + $scope.productId);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Your addToCart is out of

```
 <div ng-repeat="x in names">                                        
   <h1>{{x.product}}</h1>  
   <h2>{{x.brand}}</h2>    
   <h3>{{x.description}}</h3>  
   <h4>{{x.sum}}</h4>      
   <h5>{{x.productid}}</h5>   
    <button ng-click="addToCart(x.productid)">Add To Cart</button>      
</div>
```

in JS file

```
$scope.addToCart = function (pid) {        

    $http.post("api/shoppingCart/"+ pid);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

ng-repeat creates new scopes for each iteration. In you case, the `x` is in one of the child scopes of your ng-repeat.

The only place where you have an access to this scope is inside your view, so what you can do is the following :

```
<button ng-click="addToCart({{x.productId}})">Add To Cart</button>
```

and modifying your controller like that :

```
$scope.addToCart = function (productId) {        

    //$scope.productId = $scope.x.productid;

    $http.post("api/shoppingCart/" + productId);
}
```

You may be wondering why you have access to a parent scope inside the view, you can google angular prototypal inheritance for more info

Answer (score 0):

You can pass *productId* as a function parameter and you can use `ng-bind` instead of `{{}}` that's give you better performance and not rendered unwanted expression in DOM. if you use `{{}}` some time you see `{{x.product}}` in DOM while loading.

in HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="x in names">                                        
    <h1 ng-bind="x.product"></h1>  
    <h2 ng-bind="x.brand"></h2>    
    <h3 ng-bind="x.description"></h3>  
    <h4 ng-bind="x.sum"></h4>      
    <h5 ng-bind="x.productid"></h5>     
    <button ng-click="addToCart(x.productid)">Add To Cart</button>    
</div>
```

in controller:

```
$scope.addToCart = function (productId) {        

    $http.post("api/shoppingCart/"+ productId);
}
```